# How to keep a delay of 2 seconds in a js function ??

Tags: jquery

I have a function shown below

```
function finalcall()
{
    var vendor_brand_id = $('#BrandNames').val();
    $("#textandsavediv").hide();
    showT1(vendor_brand_id, '');
}
```

I need to keep a delay of two seconds in my functiion

Please let me know how to keep a dealy of 2 seconds ??

I know of sleep but it slows down the entire page ??

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ ?

Comment: I tried using delay but in console i am getting function undefined .

Comment: Can you update the question with that code?

Comment: Why do you want the delay?

Comment: @DarrenYoung The Ajax responses are gtting mixed up , so to make them proper .

Comment: What do you mean by getting mixed up?  It might be better if you show your ajax method as well and explain what the problem is you are having there.

Answer (score 2):

```
function finalcall()
{
    var vendor_brand_id = $('#BrandNames').val();
    $("#textandsavediv").hide();
    showT1(vendor_brand_id, '');
}

setTimeout(finalcall, 2000);
```

This runs the function `finalcall` after 2 seconds (if this is what you are going for).

Comment: Your last line has some errors. Should be `setTimeout` and you need pass the function `finalcall` without the `()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function finalcall() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var vendor_brand_id = $('#BrandNames').val();
            $("#textandsavediv").hide();
            showT1(vendor_brand_id, '');
        }, 2000);
}
```